# How to avoid Div overlap with Canvas under it?

Tags: css, canvas, flexbox, overlap

My `DIV 1` is causing overlap with the `CANVAS` causing not draggable and not clickable the object inside of it. 
How can I "hide" the area of `DIV 1`?

[image]

EDIT: 
Here we are some code:

```
.DIV1 {
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
}

.PARENT of DIV1 {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

.CANVAS {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.PARENT of everything {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried position relative with z-index. keeping a higher z-index for Canvas?

Comment: It will be more useful if you can share your code here.

Comment: @KiranDash yes I have tried, but the canvas wins every time, because it is full-width and full-height. Also, in this case, the background of the canvas can't be transparent.

Comment: @KiranDash alright, let me add some code. But it has a simple layout with flexbox nothing more

Comment: If you just want your div to not block the mouse you can always just use [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: @Aplet123 I have tried to put `pointer-events: none ` on parent of the `div1` and everything seems to work. But the buttons I have inside the `div 1` are not clickable anymore

Comment: @Elle Then you can just put `pointer-events: auto` on the buttons inside the div

Comment: @Aplet123 your solution seems working good right now. Thanks! I will wait if someone have different approach. Thanks anyway fo your time!

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `pointer-events` to get the desired results.

```
.DIV1 {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.DIV1 .child-that-need-pointer-events {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```